# Sizing page to viewport and pinning footer to bottom with Flexbox in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox

I have a Vue.js page:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex_container">
    <div class="container_navigation">
      <nav-bar />
    </div>
    <div class="container_body">
      <h1>{{ data.pages.home.heading }}</h1>
      <p>{{ data.pages.home.about}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container_footer">
      <pagefooter />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import NavBar from '...';
import Pagefooter from '...';
import siteData from '...';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Pagefooter
  },
  mounted(){  },
  computed: {  },
  data(){
    return{
      data: siteData
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.flex_container{ 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container_navigation{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container_body{
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.container_footer{
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I've played around with a few flex css tricks as detailed in the [complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) I've tried setting height: 100%; min-height: 100%; align-items:stretch; margin: auto;  etc.

None of these solutions seem to solve either of my layout problems which are

(i) The page itself ( tags) won't stretch to the entire viewport space.
(ii) I want the footer pinned to the bottom of the page.

The styling is obviously a work in progress but to outline the problem you can hopefully see in the screenshot below how the footer section is clumped up under the main body on the page and it looks kind of goofy!

[image: Page displaying with issue]

Comment: Just set height of body to 100vh. `body { height: 100vh; }`.

Comment: did you try to add `height:100%` also to `body,html`?

Comment: @לבנימלכה it will not change anything `100%` means all the content inside in body will be in body.

Comment: Try to add min-height: 100vh; to .flex_container

Comment: @KunalTanwar  I tried height: 100vh on the body element and the flex_container didn't do anything!

Comment: Try `body { height: 100vh; } .flex_container { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: @KunalTanwar Still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Ohh! dumb me why are you setting `justify-content: center;` to `.flex_container` replace it with `space-between`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments to this question were partially correct but not vue/nuxt specific!

The solution was first to edit the layouts/default.vue file to

```
<template>
  <div class="nuxt_container">
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
html {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',  Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nuxt_container{
  height: 100vh;
}

</style>
```

The crucial part here being setting height: 100vh;

The second modification was to use the layout on the pages... i.e. in pages/index.vue

```
export default Vue.extend({
  layout: 'default',
  components: {  },
  mounted(){   },
  computed: {  },
  data(){
    return{
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Where layout: 'default' , or the name of whatever your layout file is, has been added/populated!